# jdbc driver to connect to db2 7.1 as400

Tags: oracle, jdbc, db2, ibm-midrange

I need to connect to db2 7.1 as400 system using sqldeveloper & oracle data integrator using jdbc driver.

I downloaded db2cc.jar, db2cc_license_cisuz.jar..jt400.jar, db2java.jar.

The connection shows success and it appears to be connected, but while running any query or browsing any table, every time I get below error:

```
SQLCODE=-805, SQLSTATE=51002, SQLERRMC=NULLID.SYSLH200;00;S0681e7r ,DRIVER=3.59.81
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask your DB2 support person or DBA to ensure that db2clipkg.bnd is appropriately bound (or rebound) for your environment - using `db2jdbcbind`. More information at [IBM-doclink](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0606chun/index.html)

Comment: Thank You for pointers will check those with the dba..........to add my issue is exactly the same as mentioned on this url....the dbt2 version is 7.1 as400   https://community.oracle.com/message/13749695#13749695

Comment: FInally ...jt400.jar was fine....could connect using squirell, and oracle data integrator , Only sqldeveloper does not connect

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have several different and competing drivers here:

- **jt400.jar** - This is the IBM jdbc driver for DB2 on IBM i. The most recent driver can be found at [jt400.sourceforge.net](http://jt400.sourceforge.net)
- **db2jcc.jar, db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar** - This is the IBM jdbc driver for DB2 Linux, Unix, and Windows.
- **db2java.jar** - This is the Oracle DB2 driver, presumably for Linux, Unix, and Windows as the Oracle site says to use either this driver or `db2jcc.jar and db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar`, but not both.

I believe your problem is that you are trying to access DB2 on IBM i with the LUW drivers. This won't work. Of the above drivers, only `jt400.jar` is applicable. Remove the others from your classpath and then try to access the database.

Comment: The LUW driver SHOULD work to connect to IBM i.  However, if your system is configured so that the current user does not have *CHANGE authority to the NULLID library on the IBM i, then the system will not be able to autocreate the packages that are needed for the LUW driver.   I was able to produce the same error on an IBM i system by removing the *PUBLIC *CHANGE authority from the NULLID library.   By changing the authority for the user to the NULLID library to *CHANGE, I was able to get the package to create in the NULLID library.

Comment: @jweb If you have DB2 Connect